# Инсерт в таблицу множества одинаковых строк, но с разным id

Tags: sql

Есть простая таблица User

```
 Name TEXT,
 Age NUMBER,
 work TEXT
```

Надо просто вставить около 100 записей.
Дело в том что name и age одинаковые, меняется только work который обычный guid.

Этих гуидов у меня может быть очень много, в районе 1000 и я хотел бы узнать если ли какой-нить способ это сделать 1 запросом. giud разумеется заранее известны и я просто его подставляю при инсерте.

Пользуюсь PGSQL, но иногда приходится делать такие запросы и в sqlite

Comment: *Этих гуидов у меня может быть очень много, в районе 1000 и я хотел бы узнать если ли какой-нить способ это сделать 1 запросом.* Список должен быть набором записей, либо сериализованным литералом, который в запросе парсится в набор записей.

Answer (score 0):

### ДЕМО

Набор значений передаётся как JSON array.

```
CREATE TABLE test ( Name TEXT,
                    Age INTEGER,
                    work TEXT );
```

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT 'Name X',  -- значение для поля Name 
       25,        -- значение для поля Age
       value      -- значение для поля Work
-- парсинг сериализованного набора на отдельные элементы
FROM json_array_elements_text( '[
                                 "Work 1",
                                 "Work 2",
                                 "Work 3"
                                ]' );
```

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| name | age | work |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name X | 25 | Work 1 |
| Name X | 25 | Work 2 |
| Name X | 25 | Work 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rOSdL5PM)

Аналогично можно передавать набор данных, сериализованный в CSV или иной формат. В зависимости от СУБД и формата сериализации использовать соответствующую функцию.